# Select long text in spinner then create space

Tags: java, android, android-layout

when i select long text in my `spinner` then its create space between `textView` and `spinner`

**see my default** `spinner` :

[image]

**after selecting a long text it's look like below shot:**

[image]

below is xml code :

```
<TextView
                    style="@style/TextLabelBookGray"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/hint_state"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_14ssp"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_2sdp"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
                    android:id="@+id/spStates"
                    style="@style/TextLabelBookBlack"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_4sdp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_4sdp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:entries="@array/us_states"
                    />
```

below code is `style.xml`:

```
<style name="TextLabelBookGray" parent="FontBook">
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/_14ssp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/input_color_gray</item>
```

any one have any idea how to i fix it

Thanks in advance :

Comment: share xml code of spinner

Comment: wait i'll post my xml

Comment: space between textview and spinner means state is the textview?

Comment: see my xml file @Aj27

Comment: put whole xml file with this red view

Comment: red line i'll show for a spacing its not use in my code @VishvaDave

Comment: post this `style="@style/TextLabelBookBlack"` style code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165287/discussion-between-mohammad-ali-and-vishva-dave).

Comment: If you can set your spinner width in fixed side then your problem will solve automatically..buddy..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that your textView and spinner shares 50% and 50% of parent view. Better you set weightSum to parent view and allocate more width to spinner. Then you can have one line text in spinner.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="10">

            <TextView
                style="@style/TextLabelBookGray"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="2.5"
                android:text="@string/hint_state"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_14ssp"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_2sdp"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
                android:id="@+id/spStates"
                style="@style/TextLabelBookBlack"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_4sdp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_4sdp"
                android:layout_weight="7.5"
                android:entries="@array/us_states"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

This is a working example and adjust the weight according to your need.

Comment: @MohammadAli Glad i could help you. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You set spinner height as "wrap_content" so it will automatically adjust its height.You should set Spinner row's Textview max line as 1.Then it will not show double line.
Textview xml file

```
android:maxLines="1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Kush answer, Please make sure that your parent also having wrap_content so that your spinner text can show in one line. Otherwise, It will look same even if you give wrap_content to your spinner.

**Please use below code:**

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
                            android:id="@+id/spStates"
                            style="@style/TextLabelBookBlack"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_4sdp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_4sdp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:entries="@array/us_states"
                            />
```

Comment: @MohammadAli: please share entire xml layout.

Answer (score 1):

If you can set your spinner width in fixed side and weight of spinner remove then your problem will solve automatically..buddy..!

```
            <TextView
                    style="@style/TextLabelBookGray"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/hint_state"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_14ssp"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_2sdp"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
                    android:id="@+id/spStates"
                    style="@style/TextLabelBookBlack"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_4sdp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_4sdp"
                    android:entries="@array/us_states"
                    />
```

i hope it can help you..!

Answer (score 1):

you need to use android:ems in your text view and take out the weight line.

include the code below in your textview

```
android:ems="5"
```

remove the line below

```
android:layout_weight="2.5"
```

hope it helps...